# android:google login api and facebook log in api cannot use in app apk

Tags: android, facebook-login, google-signin

I link this 2 log in api with my app and it is already done in debug mode(connect my phone with my computer and press run).  When I build apk and put it to my phone and run , it doesn't work like in debug mode.

It alerts that 1. windows excption index out of bound
               2. hash key doesn't match (google result error code: 10)

I think the first problem isn't the true problem.
I think the second is the problem so I go to see the SHA-1 on my computer. It's a match with SHA-1 in developergoogle.

I run app in debug mode.

It works well. The result of google api is error code:0 (not error)

Can anyone tell me what this problem is and how to solve it ?

Comment: are you using signed apk?

Comment: I think you are using the debug keystore sha1 thats why it is working only in debug mode.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper yes i build "Generate signed APK", Oh how can i get the keystore sha-1 which can use in signed apk mode or both debug mode and apk mode?

Comment: You need to create your own keystore when you release the application. If the apk is already in the google playstore follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44671778/published-app-on-play-store-cant-communicate-with-google-maps-api-and-facebook/44672565#44672565) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44668322/google-map-not-showing-when-app-is-downloaded-from-playstore-but-showing-fine-wh/44672526#44672526) question where I already answer if you publish the apk on playstore.

Comment: You can [follow this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997748/how-can-i-create-a-keystore) if you want to create a keystore file.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper thank you it's work. :)

Comment: welcome sir : )

Comment: see my answer you can accept my answer if you think it helps you so other can found this post helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the answer for why you can't see the Google Map.**

I recently Upload the APK on Google Play store and I faced the same issue after checking the Play Console I found the solution for this problem.

Their is no problem with your key but the problem is with your SHA-1. You signed your APK with your SHA-1 that is fine and then upload the APK it also fine.

But as per the new update for Play Console when you signed your APK with SHA-1 and upload the APK it only signed by you but as per the new update it is also signed by Google Play for more security. Have a look here some part of Google Play section:

> With Google Play App Signing: You sign your app with your upload key.
>   Then, Google verifies and removes the upload key signature. Finally,
>   Google re-signs the app with the original app signing key you provided
>   and delivers your app to the user.

You can refer [Documentation here.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423)

Now, The Answer of your question is After successfully upload the APK you can see that in the section with Two SHA-1 the **1st SHA-1 is Google created** its own and **2nd SHA-1 is its yours**.

So just copy the Google SHA-1 and paste it to your console where you generate the Google Map API Key.

**How to create a keystore? You can [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997748/how-can-i-create-a-keystore).**