# Google SignIn and Facebook Login does not work every time I push an update of my app to playstore

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, google-play-services

I am currently working on an app which integrates Google and Facebook sign in. I have added the sha1 fingerprint in Firebase and have added the corresponding google-services.json file in the project and also have added the keyhash in the facebook developer console. After signing the app with release keystore the app works fine but when I push that to playstore and install it from there Google sign in does not work and in facebook login it shows invalid keyhash where has just before updating the app in playstore it worked fine.What can be the possible reasons for this?

Comment: Sounds like you're using Google Play App Signing, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44672526/4409409

Comment: @anuranbarman you need to create release **sha1 fingerprint** and update the sha1 key in google console as well as fb developer console. By doing this you can get login in google or fb.

Comment: @Daniel Nugent how to disable Google App Signing for future updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below points for solutions

1. Google changed the behavior of uploading APK Release APK and debug APK has different SHA1 and different API keys for google services. Both of them must be added in Firebase Console -> Project settings. Then download google-services.json from here, add it to project and recompile with release keystore using the option "Build signed APK".
2. When you upload an apk to the play store then play store creates a new SHA1 key called "App signing certificate". You get that SHA1 and save in your console or firebase account (as you need).

New SHA1 will be found at Released Management->App Signing on your play console.

3. please check apk when you generate signed apk build type must be release.

Comment: How to disable Google App Signing in play console for future updates?

Comment: You can't disable App Signing after being activated as you can read in the developer support :
Important: App Signing opt-in is permanent
Google Play App Signing is an optional program. If you prefer, you can continue managing your own keys.

Once you've enrolled your app in Google Play App Signing, withdrawal is not supported. To preserve the security of your app signing keys, we don't have the ability to remove keys from the secure server.

Comment: can add the new sha1 fingerprint to firebase but not able to find any option to add it in facebook console. where is that located? only keyhash option is present there.

Comment: you can delete old key hash and add the new key hash

Comment: if the problem is solved can you please accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is highly helped to me. i get the SHA1 for Android App from Google Play Console.
Then i use the below link to Generate the Key Hash and added to facebook app's Basic settings.

http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php

Thanks.